# ImageButton coming out small. Java-Android Development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made my image buttons in XML using a relative layout. They look ok when I've made them but when I run it on my phone it comes out small! I want it to expand to the width of my device (or the width of any device it goes to)

Here's my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/prewedbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weddingbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/prewedbutton"
    android:src="@drawable/prewedbutton" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/weddingbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="103dp"
    android:contentDescription="@drawable/weddingbutton"
    android:src="@drawable/weddingbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Java:

```
package com.example.ijazphotography;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.content.Intent;

public class PhotographyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photography);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.

        ImageButton prewed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prewedbutton);
        prewed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PreWedActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });

        ImageButton wed = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.weddingbutton);
        wed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Wedding.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with  android:layout_width="fill_parent" or  android:layout_width="match_content"

Comment: Is it "wrap_content" so the ImageView or the layout itself is in cause here, not the code IMO.

Comment: You should use match_parent instead wrap_content to expand button's width or height to screen size.

Comment: @sany I tried that, doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` , and tell me your results please.

Comment: you're welcome! Please mark the answer like correct :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent" and it should expand to device width.

Comment: That expands the button for me but not the image inside, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your buttons to occupy parent width then you can change the width of button to fill_parent

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: fill_parent deprecated since API8

Comment: @Wishmaster, Thanks for your info. you can use match_parent as per new api